# iPad Application shows app icon as launch screen in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ipad, ios10, xcode8

In iPad `iOS 10` Application shows app icon as launch screen / Splash screen if we don't provide any launch screen.

I had not set any launch screen or image.

[image]

And LaunchImage asset is blank.

[image]

It looks weird.

see

[image]

Is it bug ? or feature?

FYI

Application is not in App Store it's enterprise app.

Comment: is this issue in all other ios versions ? What happens if i build an app in Xcode 7.3 and install in iOS 10 ?

Comment: Same issue, It is related to iOS 10.

Comment: did u solve this issue ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is what happens by default in xcode 8 if no launch image is specified - I used a LaunchScreen.storyboard to solve it

Comment: @ToseefKhilji I am having the same issue right now. How do you solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: My launch image isnt empty yet I get this error only for ipad running ios10 , has anyone figured this out yet?

Comment: @ishhhh, EISS : Not yet.

Answer (score 7):

I was also getting this issue in my app for iPad and I found solution of this.

**Solution:** I added a `launchscreen.xib`  in my app and select this file in to LaunchScreen section of 'General' section in target window.

I did not add launch images of iPad devices, may be this is the reason of issue.

So now this issue has resolved.  :)

[image]

Comment: Yes thats the issue. If we don't provide either launch screen or image then it shows app icon as launch screen.

Comment: No ajeet, I can't. It misleads others.

Comment: not working here. When I set a LaunchScreen.nib or LaunchScreen.storyboard it's shown after the Icon was resized to fullscreen.

Comment: Is it required to give launch screen. In my case, I do not require launch screen. In iOS 9.3 without launch screen, everything was working fine. When I ran same application on iOS 10 in simulator, I got this issue of zooming of icon on application launch.

Comment: Remember to also have Launch Screen file assigned in your info.plist
I did not have it and it worked when I've build app from XCode, but when I ran it from my IPA file it still had this issue of zoomed app icon.

Comment: I had the same issue, but adding launch screen xib or storyboard not fix this issue. do anybody has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @ToseefKhilji  I am using Launch Image in Launch Image Source. It was working fine till yesterday. Suddenly now, app. icon is enlarged and shown as launch image. This happens only in iPhone 6+ iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the animation that is used to give the "zoom" effect from the app icon when the user launches your app.

You will notice that the launch image animates it's alpha from `0.0` to `1.0` as the user opens the app.

In your case, you have not specified an image so there is nothing to show. This is something that isn't supported as your app would be rejected if you tried to submit to iTunes Connect. You should always ensure that you have a launch image (or nib) set, even if it's just a plain white image.

---

You could probably try filing a bug report about it but my expectation will be that you are just told to add image resources to the asset in the Assets Catalog.

Comment: Thanks @liamnichols, I have filled a bug.

Comment: No problem. May i ask what the problem is with just setting a white image? You could also try removing the "LaunchImage" asset as well to see how it handles it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the launch screen issue by sure.
Set launch screen in .plist file. It should be solved.

For iOS less than 9.0 you can set image as launch screen and for others you need launch screen as XIB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to support iPad target at "Targeted Device Family" of your Build Settings

Settings at "Targeted Device Family" is like these. 
1 is iPhone only
2 is iPad only
1,2 is iPhone/iPad Both.

In my case, if i choose "1,2", app icon launch image has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone's still struggling with this. My problem was an entirely different thing. For me the "Slow Animation" were on in the iOS simulator. I probably had accidentally hit CMD + T. You can turn it off from iOS Simulator menu Debug -> Slow Animation.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

We can add a launch screen from the new file menu and then set it in the general settings on the application.

or you can also add images in images.xcassets with the name Launchimage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add images to project with following names :

**Notes : All are not required you need to add per requirement**

```
  320x480(2x) ->   640x960: Default@2x~iphone.png
  320x568(2x) ->  640x1136: Default-568h@2x~iphone.png
  375x667(2x) ->  750x1334: Default-667h@2x~iphone.png
  414x736(3x) -> 1242x2208: Default-736h@3x~iphone.png
  768x1024(1x) ->  768x1024: Default-Portrait~ipad.png
  1024x768(1x) ->  1024x768: Default-Landscape~ipad.png
  768x1024(2x) -> 1536x2048: Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
  1024x768(2x) -> 2048x1536: Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
```