# iPad running iOS 10 shows app icon resized instead of launch image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm having a similar issue to this question below here but it only happens in iPad running iOS10.. the launch screen shows the app icon resized instead of showing the launch image. Unlike the question below, I have set launch images in image assets and referenced it in info.plist, its not empty and it shows perfectly on iPhone. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

[iPad Application shows app icon as launch screen in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571694/ipad-application-shows-app-icon-as-launch-screen-in-ios-10)

[image: launch screen image]

Comment: Please try to add Launchscreen.xib file and place image view over xib.

Comment: can U post screenshot of .xcassets - LaunchImage ?

Comment: @byJeevan I have created a universal Launch Screen xib and this seems to solve the issue

Comment: @ElSS glad you solved it !!. Shall I post an answer based on your comment ?

Comment: @jeevan yes please post it